# Are there applications for the cancellation of one-loop divengeces in $SO(8192)$ bosonic string theory?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, string-field-theory

I recently read in Polchinski's textbook on string theory (Volume One, page 229) that an orientifold of the 26-dimensional bosonic string can be considered. Investigating further, I found that after computing the cylinder and Mobius strip partition functions for such orientifold a divergence due to massless states can be cancelled if one adds 8192 $D$-25 branes "on top" of the space-filling $O$-25 orientifold plane. The reference is [Cancellation of One Loop Divergences in SO(8192) String Theory](https://inspirehep.net/literature/21243).

The fact looks pretty interesting and of the type of "miracles" that string theory is full of.  Obviously is remminicent of the tadpole cancellation for the type I orientifold of the IIB superstring theory.

Nevertheless, I'm not aware of any situation in which this construction has been proven to be important at all and I haven't found one.

**My question** is just simple curiosity. **Is there any application of the tadpole cancellation for the bosonic string orientifold?**

Further reference: Chapter Six of the textbook "Introduction to conformal field theory" by Ralph Blumenhagen and Erik Plauschinn.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @NiharKarve. I was aware of that comment before asking this question. My motivation to ask was simply the hope to know if this fact has appeared in some development or application after Polchinski's comment in his textbook (2005-2021).